# Syntactically correct fopen not working in Windows. Errno == 2

Tags: c, windows

I got the following code there:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    errno = 0; 
    FILE * fp; 
    fp = fopen(  "output.txt"  , "a"  );  
    if (!fp )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "creating file failed. errno = %d.", errno);
//I already tried it with the full path C:\\...\\...\\...\\ blabla
        exit(1);
    }
    fwrite("hello", sizeof(char),sizeof("hello"),fp); 
    fclose(fp); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I used fopen like a thousand times (actually i'm not that unexperienced), however after compiling it in g++, this simple code seems not to be working. The program exits always with errno == 2.

Maybe it has something to do with the access control, idk.
Maybe the windows kernel wants to
I'm getting a bit confused there.
Other mentions:
I used vscode to code it, and compiled it a bunch of time in an internal shell, which I
understand as just a simple Powershell.
I tried to compile and run it externally, it doesn t work.
My Antivirus is standard.

hope you can help me out!
thx

I want to write a file, using a simple file pointer, fwrite and fclose.
thx.

Comment: `//I already tried it with the full path C:\\...\\...\\...\\ blabla` -- How do we know this was correct?  How do we know if that file even exists?  Unless we have access to your machine, no one will know what the issue is.

Comment: You could print an error message using `perror()`. Also: `fwrite("hello", 0,sizeof("hello"),fp);`  What is `0` supposed to do as the size?

Comment: Since you use FILE* I assume you have a "C" question. If that's the case then remove the C++ tag. If you use a C++ compiler then remove the "C" tag. C and C++ are different langauges for which you can expect different answers.

Comment: Is the file located in your workspace folder? If you build using VS Code, what is the complete output in your console? Is there some `cd ... && gcc .... & ...`? Does the folder that is used, match your expectation?

Comment: tried it now to compile it as test.c with gcc. and still "creating file failed. errno = 2."

Comment: Gerhardh. yes. and the binary too. I will try it to execute in another folder.

Comment: You could search your compiler's include folder and check in `errno.h` what the value 2 means. I would expect it to be `ENOENT` which means the file is not found. Using `perror` would also show that. But on the other side.... Using `"a"` should create the file....

Comment: Ok I tried to execute it in another folder: I still got this error.

Comment: thx for the information. I already know this (I looked up errno == 2). so it got to be the antivirus or some restrictions i'm not aware about.

Comment: maybe my mingw is corrupt, idk. this is bonkers

Comment: Ok now after i mv it to a .c file and another folder which is not workspace of vscode, i now compiled the code and I still got this error.

Comment: guess I need to do my file operations with systems call, python and argc.

Comment: and there are still some ideas with icalcs and attrib

Comment: Gerhardh. the code fails already at fopen which returns NULL, which leads to  fprintf(stderr, "creating file failed. errno = %d.", errno); and exit(1),   So the output is "creating file failed. errno = 2".  i normally use makefiles. here for this simple example i used gcc/g++ by command line.

Comment: Hmm, this is rather simple code, and I cannot imagine what it could fail. But while being a very nice piece of code, VSCode depends on its *configuration json files*. And an error there leads to nightmares for finding and fixing it. My advice: 1. try to compile and test the code at the command line level to confirm that the problem is in VSCode config 2. Try to create a brand new environment in VSCode. Other possible problem: the file that you execute is not the file generated from this source code...

Comment: I understand. I just wanted to avoid that you immediately run into the next problem with wrong size

Comment: Serge Ballesta. I did compile it via command line (powershell) in another folder which is not workspace. It still doesn't work, and I don't know why.  I'm heavily confused.

Comment: ok i got the following additional information:  i wrote a python code, which creates a file and writes it with the argv, the executed it once in the project folder, while vscode running, and then i executed it in another folder, which is not vscode project folder with following results -  python code outside the project folder work, however not the once executed in the project folder

Comment: ok update: works with this code here too. seems to be that in the last testcode I forgot to change the path, due to stressed.